# SQL Server getting modified column name using sys.fn_dblog

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

```
SELECT
s.[operation],
s.[transaction name],
s.[context],
s.[allocunitname],
s.[page id],
s.[slot id],
s.[begin time],
s.[end time],
from sys.fn_dblog(NULL,NULL) as s 
where operation IN 
('LOP_INSERT_ROWS','LOP_MODIFY_ROW',
'LOP_DELETE_ROWS','LOP_BEGIN_XACT','LOP_COMMIT_XACT')
```

I use this select query to retrieve operation logs from sys.fn_dblog.I can get the table name from allocaunitname and row number from slot id. I also want to see modified column name. Is this possible?